# Java.lang.Class.newInstance() throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jar, javafx

I have simple `Start` class with `public Start(String[] params)` constructor, which I'm calling from a non-runnable JAR file from the level of other running Java program. Everything is working in runtime environment. The problem occurs, when I try to call newInstance() method, in order to invoke this `Start` class.

Class `Start` looks like this:

```
public class Start {

    public Start(String[] params) {

        /* initialize MainStage object */
        MainStage stage = new MainStage(params);
        stage.show();
        // MainStage DO NOT have any restriction about params.length
    }
}
```

And that's how I'm calling `Start` class:

```
String[] t = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.plugin.Start");
    /* line below throws the mentioned exception */
    clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class).newInstance((Object[]) t);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is worth mentioning, that everything except this `IllegalArgumentException` goes just perfect, that means - JAR is added to the runtime classpath, class `Start` is calling out without problem, when it has no parameters in its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an array of objects, and put `t` in it, like this:

```
clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class).newInstance(new Object[]{t});
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/eEgB46)

The reason Java tells you that you have passed an invalid number of parameters is that your code passes `t`, an array with three elements, to a constructor that takes a single array parameter. In other words, you were missing an extra level of indirection, because parameters that you pass to methods or constructors need to be wrapped in `Object[]` that has one element per function parameters.

Comment: Now everything works flawlessly. Thank you very much. PS so thats why IDE was screaming at me `Type String[] of the last argument to method newInstance(Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.`